# How to fix " No input source set" error in Java [mac]

Tags: java, tesseract

I'm having trouble showing the file path in java on mac.

How can ı fix ?

```
    File imageFile = new File("Users/emircanaydin/Desktop/deneme.png");
    ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();

    try
    {
        String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    catch (TesseractException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

[main] ERROR net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract - No input source set!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No input source set!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.getNumImages(PNGImageReader.java:1355)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:221)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:195)
    at OCRBasedReceiptReader.Main.main(Main.java:29)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No input source set!

Comment: Most likely your file path is incorrect, perhaps add some validation of it to the code

Comment: Try to verify `imageFile.exists()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error whit the latest version of tess4j (maven dependency) 4.5.1, and I downgrade the version of tess4j to 4.0.0 and it works.

May be this will help you!

And also, I think it is't related to your mac, if your path is right.